# Connectedness and Components in $S^2$

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Let $K$ be a closed and connected subset of the two-dimensional sphere $S^2$
and let $a \in K$. Is $a$ in the closure of every connected component $C$ of $K\setminus \{a\}$?

Comment: Considered a component $C$ of $K \setminus \{a\}$ whose closure would not contain $\{a\}$. The closure of $C$ is connected; since it is a subset of $K$ and does not contain $a$, as $C$ is maximal among connected subsets of $K \setminus \{a\}$, $C$ is closed. Now, can we prove that it's also a maximally connected subset of $K$? That would contradict the assumption that $K$ is connected. Note: I am not actually sure that the result holds and that I should not search for a counter-example instead of a proof.

Comment: I have a counterexample in $\mathbb{R}^2$ but not in $S^2$. So compactness must be important.